# Regex for 10 digit number in which doesn't allow all zeros, all single nos and sequence nos

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to have one phone number field in my page with following req: 
1. no should be 10 digits. 
2. no all single nos allowed like all 0's or all 1's, etc. 
3. and sequence of number also not allowed. from 0 to 9 and 9 to 0.

till now I have this regex
/^(?!0+$)\d{10}$/ 
I am using negative lookahead (?!0+$) in expression for not allowing all 0's.
by replacing 0 with 1,2,3,etc, i can disallow any other number also. 
but i am not able to find out solution for rest of requirements.

valid inputs:
9988737634
1235876656

invalid inputs:
2763
0000000000
1111111111
0123456789
9876543210

Can anybody help?
or if not possible in regex can anybody with javascript code to do same?
thanks.

Comment: What is a "single no"? What is a "sequence of number"? (Is `45` a sequence? How about `654`? How about `2468`?) How do you know phone numbers won't have sequences? (Not about phone numbers, but [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) is very educational.)

Comment: single number is any number like all zeros or all ones or so...
and all 10 number should not make any sequence. in between sequence can be there

Comment: The only sequences possible with 10 digits (under the normal understanding of the word "sequences") are `0123456789` and `9876543210`. You don't need regex to test for that. You really need to define your terms more precisely, giving examples and counterexamples.

Comment: thanks @Amadan i just confirmed requirements, you are right. i have updated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^(?!(\d)\1{9})(?!0123456789|1234567890|0987654321|9876543210)\d{10}$`

You can use something like the pattern above. You need to spell out the sequences because there is nothing built into regex that checks for sequences, TMK. The check for all zeros or all "single digits" can be accomplished by the same negative lookeahead. Within that lookahead, you can make use of a capture group to simplify the pattern.